# iOS live camera overlay AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, cocoa, avcapturesession

So this is a general question but was looking for a lead on how to have the live camera view with the ability to add images on top and take a pic. So basically you can select like a "Hat" image that overlays on the camera, adjust its size and position, then take a pic and the "Hat" will be on the image you took. I saw a few directions like AVCaptureSession but was not sure if anyone has done something like this to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer how to add a video layer:

[Get Camera Preview to AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515921/get-camera-preview-to-avcapturevideopreviewlayer)

You could add a subview on the top of your video view and then take a screenshot:

[Why does my programmatically created screenshot look so bad on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956611/programmatically-screenshot-works-bad-on-ios-7)