# How to capture screen video with audio and custom face camera in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avassetwriter, screen-recording

I want to capture video with audio and custom face camera from my screen.

I am unable to capture video with audio and face camera from my screen. But it can not record audio and face camera.

I am using `AVAssetWriter`.

I am also using this demo classes https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder

check it out.

In this demo it only records screen, but i want to record screen with audio and face camera. Where the face camera is in small size at left bottom corner.

Comment: Add your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: i am using ASScreenRecorder classes. i get from github.

Comment: This is the link  https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder

Comment: This is screen recorder, not video and audio recorder, try this https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder

Comment: yes you are right, but i want to record my screen playing videos, like i have an browser and i am playing videos from YouTube and i want to record that video with sound and face camera. where the face camera should be a small size like 80*80 in left down corner.

Comment: In that case you can simply use AVCaptureDevice and setup a small front camera.. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19802099/790842